# OpenPojo JUnit validation field names from abbreviations

Tags: java, web-services, junit, pojo

I'm trying to test the Pojo classes generated from wsdl to improve code coverage and I'm facing an issue I don't know how to solve.

The generated class looks like this:

```
 public class NOF implements java.io.Serializable {    

   private java.lang.String nOFName;    

   public java.lang.String getNOFName() {
     return this.nOFName;
   }

   public void setNOFName(java.lang.String nOFName) {
     this.nOFName = nOFName;
   }

 }
```

It looks like the Pojo Validator doesn't correctly translate the variable name `nOFName` to a getter `getNOFName` and looks for something else instead(I don't know what). Exception I get is this:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: [PojoFieldImpl [field=private java.lang.String 
mypackage.NOF.nOFName, fieldGetter=null, fieldSetter=null]] is missing a getter
```

When I change the name of the variable to `NOFName`, the test passes. It also works if I change it to `nofName` and rename method to `getNofName`. I know the problem is in the name made out of abbreviation, but I really don't want to change the generated classes, because they may be regenerated in the future. 
Do I need to write a custom validator? I guess somoene must have dealt with the problem before(because I see this as a perfect use-case for openpojo validation), but I haven't found anything.

The test looks like this:

```
public class PojoTest {
    @Test
    public void testPojo() throws Exception{
        PojoValidator validator = new PojoValidator();
        validator.addRule(new GetterMustExistRule());
        validator.addRule(new SetterMustExistRule());
        validator.addTester(new GetterTester());
        validator.addTester(new SetterTester());
        for (PojoClass cls: PojoClassFactory.getPojoClasses("mypackage")){
            validator.runValidation(cls);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
I've debugged the openpojo library and it searches for `getnOFName` and there's nothing I can do about it except fix and recompile the library :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is not very straightforward, but quite easy. I had to mock the Pojo Validation library(I still laugh at that idea). Here's the working code:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(AttributeHelper.class)
public class PojoTest {
    static  PojoValidator validator;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass(){
        validator = new PojoValidator();
        validator.addRule(new GetterMustExistRule());
        validator.addRule(new SetterMustExistRule());
        validator.addTester(new GetterTester());
        validator.addTester(new SetterTester());
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        PowerMockito.replace(method(AttributeHelper.class, "formattedFieldName")).with(method(PojoTest.class, "formattedFieldName"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testPojo() throws Exception {
        for (PojoClass cls: PojoClassFactory.getPojoClasses("mypackage")){
               validator.runValidation(cls);
        }
    }

    private static final List<String> fieldPrefixes = new LinkedList<String>();

    private static String formattedFieldName(final String fieldName) {
        return fieldName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + fieldName.substring(1, fieldName.length());
    }
}
```

The problem is that the wsdl2java has different interpretation of the Java Beans standard(inferred names), than PojoValidator. I had to replace one static method from the library.